# mongodump and mongorestore command not found mac

Tags: mongodb

I intalled mongodb by the following steps

- Downloaded mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.0.tgz
- sudo mv mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.0.tgz  /usr/local/mongodb
- mkdir -p /data/db
- sudo chown myusername /data/db
- mongod

Now the mongodb server is started and running, I need to import my db with the backup I have.
I tried importing data with the following command

- mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db dbName /Users/userName/Downloads/mongo

It throws

- mongorestore: command not found

How can I install mongostore and mongodumb seperately? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the tools package.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As of [MongoDB 4.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4) (released July 30, 2020), you need to install `mongodump` separately because the MongoDB Database Tools (which comprises `mongodump`, `mongorestore`, and more) [has become its own project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4/#migration-to-mongodb-database-tools-project).

I found this out because I upgraded to MongoDB 4.4 today and `mongodump` stopped working.

```
$ mongodump
zsh: command not found: mongodump
```

I'm on macOS and installed MongoDB via Homebrew. To get `mongodump` and friends back, I installed the MongoDB Database Tools via Homebrew:

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

```sh
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

It looks like you're not using Homebrew, so this should help:

[MongoDB Database Tools Installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation/)

Comment: Thank you @ptrkcsk

Comment: I had to `brew tap mongodb/brew` before the install would work.

Comment: On Windows, the steps are the same: `choco install mongodb-database-tools`

Comment: MongoDB tools link is broken

Comment: Thanks, @Bn.F76. Fixed.